# PHP error handling with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, security, .htaccess

I've been reading a couple of articles on website security and they recommend adding this code to your `.htaccess` file to prevent the display of PHP errors:

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

If I add this code **directly** into my `.htaccess` file I am given a 500 internal server error. What's wrong with it? Is this all deprecated stuff?

Answer (score 4):

It does in fact depend on the [`PHP SAPI`](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP%20SAPI). This precise `.htaccess` syntax will only work with `mod_php` setups, not with `CGI` or `FastCGI` installations. In the latter case you would use a [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) (for PHP 5.3 onwards) instead.

Most of the options you have there can however be configured at runtime. Use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) atop the invocation script:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```

Note that for `_startup_errors` it's obviously too late to be configured there. Also it's redundant to disable `html_errors` and the docref things if `display_errors` is already off.

Comment: Will that code, `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` disable **all** php erros?

Comment: It'll disable the **display** of all errors. With the default error handler. It does not affect logging or a custom error handler. And `error_reporting(0);` would have the same outcome.

Comment: turning html errors off is not redundant. PHP happily writing HTML into text logs too :)

Answer (score 4):

For security, it's better not to display the errors but remember to make sure their logging is enabled, so you can see the errors happening in the site and trace their sources.

In .htaccess you can write:

```
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value error_log /path/php_error_log
```

Also since you are using .htaccess, you can have your own custom error pages:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error500.html
```

Answer (score -2):

The best option is to disable the errors from php.ini, because in some cases if you do it vía .htaccess will give an Internal Server Error. ;)

Comment: disabling error reporting is the same as sweeping things under the carpet, as well as being a security risk. Logging errors allows one to identify problems and resolve them.